# Prevent multiple ssh-tunnel to same port and ip

Tags: ssh, tunnel, openssh, ssh-tunnel

Im creating a few ssh-tunnel connections to a remote system with this command:

`ssh -R port:localhost:2222 user@ip`

If this command is now execute multiple times, it will create every time a new connection.
Is it possible to prevent this? I like to have only 1 connection per port and ip-address.

Answer (score 0):

I did this command:

```
ssh -R 3333:localhost:2222 <host>
```

The first time it worked. In another terminal, I ran it again, and got this:

```
Error: remote port forwarding failed for listen port 3333
```

which is what I would expect.

It works fine exactly as you posted.

What doesn't work?

Comment: Here, ssh -L creates an additional process every time, besides refusing to stablish a new tunnel. Which is not ideal.

Answer (score 0):

To avoid spawning additional processes (instead of tunnel, because there will be only one):

```
ssh -R port:localhost:2222 user@ip -o ExitOnForwardFailure=yes
```